# Compare two arrays with two conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets, call worksheet1 = GoldCopy and worksheet2 = OPS, both with several of the same columns:
column 1 = Filename, column 3 = file path, column 4 = encryption code, and column 5 = in goldcopy (or OPS depending on which ws you're looking at).

There are 10,000+ rows of data. I want to compare ws1 with ws2 and make sure the filename and encryption code from ws1 is in ws2 (doesn't matter where as long as filename and encryption code are in the same row).
If there is a filename and encryption code that is not in ws2, then that column 5 at that row will be made FALSE.
Then I want to compare ws2 to ws1 with the same logic.

I tried two for loops but it has taken forever to finish. I want to try arrays. I'm having trouble with the 'IF' statements which I will label below.

This is the first part of the code with ws1 checking ws2. I assume to have ws2 check against ws1, it would be the same code, just switched around.

```vb
Sub CheckforDiscrepancies 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim s As Worksheet

    For Each s In Sheets
        'NEW FILE SEARCH A-NAS OPS'
        If s.Name = "OPS" Then 'check if there is an OPS file if so then proceed'
        ACOL = Worksheets("OPS").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Worksheets("OPS").Cells(1, ACOL + 1).Value = "In Gold Copy?"

        
        'GoldCopy Check with OPS'
        Worksheets("GoldCopy").Activate
        GCOL = Worksheets("GoldCopy").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Worksheets("GoldCopy").Cells(1, GCOL + 1) = "Deployed in  OPS?"

        Dim arrayGoldRow As Variant
        Dim arrayGoldRow2 As Variant
        Dim arrayARow As Variant
        Dim arrayARow2 As Variant
        
        arrayGoldRow = Worksheets("GoldCopy").Range("A:A").Value          'this should be column 1 the filename for the goldcopy
        arrayARow = Worksheets("OPS").Range("A:A").Value           'this should be column 1 for the filename for the ops sheet
        arrayGoldRow2 = Worksheets("GoldCopy").Range("D:D").Value             'this should be column 4 for the encryption code for the goldcopy 
        arrayARow2 = Worksheets("OPS").Range("D:D").Value           'this should be column 4 for the encryption code for the ops sheet 

        
        For i = LBound(arrayGoldRow, 1) To UBound(arrayGoldRow, 1)
            GCOL = Worksheets("GoldCopy").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If InStr(Worksheets("GoldCopy").Cells(i, 3), "\sidata\") > 0 Then       'this is checking column 3 to see if the filepath fits a certain criteria
                For x = LBound(arrayARow, 1) To UBound(arrayARow, 1)        'not sure if this is correct of not 
                    If Worksheets("GoldCopy").Cells(i,1) = Worksheets("OPS").Cells(j,1) and Worksheets("GoldCopy").Cells(j,4) = Worksheets("OPS").Cells(j,4) Then           'this is saying is filename in column1 and encyrption code in column2 from the goldcopy BOTH match with the filename in column1 and encyrption code in column2 from the ops sheet, then...
                        bln = True
                        Worksheets("GoldCopy").Cells(i, GCOL) = bln 
                        Worksheets("GoldCopy").Cells(i, GCOL).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        Worksheets("GoldCopy").Cells(i, GCOL) = bln
                        Worksheets("GoldCopy").Cells(i, GCOL).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
                    End If
                Next x
            End If
        Next i
```

Comment: Before even looking for any bugs or faulty logic i'm seeing that you are not limiting the scope of your arrays to the minimal data required. Instead of loading the **entire** column into the array, just load the required range (i.e. usually loading up until the last used row). This will minimize your `UBOUND` and in return the number of iterations in your loop.

Comment: It seems kind of pointless to use an array here... you're not actually using the elements of the arrays at all. Your comparisons are always made against a specific cell. If you want to use the array, then use the array.

Comment: `GCOL = Worksheets("GoldCopy").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` should not be inside the loop either.

Comment: yeah sorry i wasnt sure if making comparisons against specific cells was allowed....very new to all this stuff so still trying to learn. I tried using two for loops, one to go through the first ws1 then for loop to ws2 and compare each cell but that took a really long time and I have to do this to several other sheets so I wanted to see what was a better option.

Comment: urdearboy how would I minimize ubound ?  I thought thats sort of what I did with the ubound[arrayGoldRow] but i guess that was incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I would tackle the task. Please try my code. It uses the COUNTIFS worksheet function to check if the combination of file and code exists. You could extend this to include the path. It also uses the same function, called with file names reversed, to check availability both ways.

```
Enum Nws                    ' worksheet parameters
    ' 118
    NwsFirstDataRow = 2     ' change to suit
    NwsFile = 1             ' columns: 1 = column A
    NwsPath = 3             '          3 = column C
    NwsCode                 ' no value assigned means previous + 1
    NwsCheck
End Enum

Sub CompareTabs()
    ' 118

    Dim WsOps       As Worksheet
    Dim WsGold      As Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WsOps = Worksheets("OPS")
    Set WsGold = Worksheets("GoldCopy")
    If Err Then Exit Sub                    ' exit if one of the sheets doesn't exist
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Debug.Print MarkDiscrepancies(WsOps, WsGold)
    Debug.Print MarkDiscrepancies(WsGold, WsOps)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub

Private Function MarkDiscrepancies(Ws1 As Worksheet, _
                                   Ws2 As Worksheet) As Boolean
    ' 118
    ' return True if a discrepancy was found and marked

    Dim Src     As Variant          ' Source = base data
    Dim Scode   As Variant          ' Src encryption codes
    Dim Tgt     As Range            ' Target = range to find Src data in
    Dim Tcode   As Range            ' Tgt encryption codes
    Dim R       As Long             ' loop counter: rows in Ws1
    
    With Ws2
        Set Tgt = .Range(.Cells(1, NwsFile), .Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsFile).End(xlUp))
    End With
    Set Tcode = Tgt.Offset(, NwsCode - NwsFile)
    With Ws1
        Src = .Range(.Cells(1, NwsFile), .Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsFile).End(xlUp)).Value
        Scode = .Range(.Cells(1, NwsFile), .Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsFile).End(xlUp)) _
                       .Offset(, NwsCode - NwsFile).Value
        
        For R = NwsFirstDataRow To UBound(Src)
            On Error Resume Next
            .Cells(R, NwsCheck).Value = CBool(WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Tgt, Src(R, 1), Tcode, Scode(R, 1)))
        Next R
        MarkDiscrepancies = CBool(WorksheetFunction.CountIf( _
                           .Range(.Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsCheck), _
                           .Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsCheck).End(xlUp)), False))
    End With
End Function
```

The function that does the work returns True or False, depending upon whether discrepancies were found. It prints the result to the Immediate Pane. You might show it in a MsgBox or just call the function like a sub (without parentheses) and take your information from column E - as, in fact, does my code.

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to look at this! Testing this out now :)